# Display a txt file on website in a message box in vb

Tags: vb.net, text

How can a msgbox in vb pull a text from a txt file from a website and view it show it in a message box on a form. For example if there was a txt file at http://example.com/tip.txt how can i view that txt in a messagebox when activated in vb

msgbox(*Show_txt_from_txt_file_from_website*) ?

Im just doing this so im able to have this application a serverside application and i can change the txt of the message without having to update / publish the application again. Its kindof hard to explain what im trying to say but i hope someone understand my issue

Comment: Why don't you parse the text file, save that data as a string and then use the [.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/519bytz3(v=vs.110).aspx) method to append that to the `MessageBox`?

Comment: Ive tried that and for some reason it didnt work. It may be something dealing with my permissions of files on my website. But @Joel_Coehoorn gave me something that i was able to use and it worked. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick'n'Dirty:

```
MsgBox((New System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadString("http://example.com/tip.txt") )
```

Better:

```
Using wc As New WebClient()
    MessageBox.Show(wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/tip.txt"))
End Using
```

Comment: And this is why you have 185k rep and I have a paltry 59 :) +1.